# replaceReducer on @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: redux-toolkit, code-splitting

Although I'm newbie of redux as well as of RTK, I'm just starting redux project with RTK as if you start with Spring Boot not Spring these days.

I want to [dynamically inject reducers on demand](https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting#using-replacereducer) on redux toolkit(RTK). I realized that I `need to keep track of current reducers` to make it. I expected my store from RTK would have a reference to them, but unfortunately it seems it doesn't have such a property.

While I found [this module](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/redux-injectors) that seems to do the job, but it seems I have to go back to the days before RTK was created to make it work.

```
import {createStore, createReducer, Slice, Reducer, AnyAction, combineReducers} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const Store = createStore<any, any, any, any>(createReducer({}, () => {}));

const reducers: {
    [key: string]: Reducer<any, AnyAction>;
} = {};

export const injectReducer = (slice: Slice) => {
    reducers[slice.name] = slice.reducer;
    Store.replaceReducer(combineReducers(reducers));
};
```

Even more (maybe I just don't know the way) type definitions will go insane.

Is there any way to make this?

Comment: Honestly this is a very advanced design pattern and if you’re a newbie I would not recommend it.

Comment: Hi @Changdae Park, did you find your answer? I working on something related and wanted to know your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Arman Nah, I stopped looking into this, as I'm using `nextjs` + `next-redux-wrapper` now which makes me apart further from this matter.

Comment: @ChangdaePark, Thanks. Anyway, I managed it and I finally have it, I can share it if you are still interested.

Comment: @Arman oh please make your answer, I can't wait to see it :)

Comment: @ChangdaePark sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be in a store enhancer form:

```
const injectReducerEnhancer: StoreEnhancer = (createStore) => (...args) => {
  const store = createStore(...args);
  store.asyncReducers = {};

  store.injectReducer = (key, asyncReducer) => {
    store.asyncReducers[key] = asyncReducer;
    store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
  };

  return store;
};
function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
   return combineReducers({
     ...staticReducers,
     ...asyncReducers
   });
};
configutreStore({
  enhancers: [injectReducerEnhancer],
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and finally managed to fix it with a few lines;

First, I created the store:

```js
const staticReducers = {
  counter: counterReducerSlice,
};

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: staticReducers,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => [logger, ...getDefaultMiddleware()],
  enhancers: compose([monitorReducerEnhancer]),
});
```

then making the async reducers directory:

```js
store.asyncReducers = {};

store.injectReducer = (key, asyncReducer) => {
  store.asyncReducers[key] = asyncReducer;
  store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
};

function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    ...staticReducers,
    ...asyncReducers
  });
}
```

finally, in my code, every time I want to add a new `reducer` to my store, I call `store.injectReducer`:

```js
store.injectReducer('reducerKey', theReducerSlice);
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to see of how you use `store.injectReducer` in a component!